# Why is conda rejecting every version of python I try?

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install a package from Anaconda Cloud called [pyradiomics](https://anaconda.org/Radiomics/pyradiomics). So I wrote this Dockerfile:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest
RUN conda install -c radiomics pyradiomics
```

which errored out with the message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pyradiomics -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

The error message seems to indicate I need version 3.8 of python specifically, so I tried to install that

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:latest
RUN conda install -c anaconda python=3.8 && python --version && conda install -c radiomics pyradiomics
```

but now get the error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pyradiomics -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.4,<3.5.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8
```

When I have python 3.7 it wants 3.8 and when I have 3.8 it wants some other version. Is there a way to get conda to automagically resolve these version issues and install (all) the version(s) of python necessary? Or how would I best manually resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.8 doesn't seem to be supportd as per https://pyradiomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#install-via-conda, though the 3.7 install conditions might contain an error.

In this case you can try to contact the authors or try with pip.